# Excel 2010 VBA to remove duplicates and then sumif base on the unique data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

My work requires data comparison from 2 different sources (sheet 1 is source 1 and sheet 2 is source 2). Both sheets contain duplicate values (the Delivery Order)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/mjEtTdb.png]

Because I need to do this kind of task very often so I really need a VBA to help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What will be result of data comparison - should the duplicate data be deleted or should they be highlighted using a given color?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to accomplish this without using VBA.

Copy the **Delivery order** column from *Sheet 1* to *Sheet 3* column A

In *Sheet 3*, Column B use the following formula `vlookup(A2,![sheet1]A2:A10,2,0)`. This will bring the Quantity from *Sheet 1* to *Sheet 3* Column B

In *Sheet 3*, Column C use the following formula `vlookup(A2,![sheet2]A2:A10,2,0)`. This will bring the Quantity from *Sheet 2* to *Sheet 3* Column B

In column D, you can do `B-C`as you noted.